# Is this sentence correct? Only my wrist hurts because I didn't use the seat-belts and I held on to the hand while braking

Tags: american-english

1. „Only my wrist hurts because I didn't use the seat-belts and I held on to the hand while braking”

Or

2. „Only my wrist hurts because I didn't use the seat-belts and I held on to my hand while braking”

Is this correct or not?

Comment: Is _only_ intended to be the limiting modifier ('It's only my wrist that hurts ...') or the introducing-a-related-question pragmatic marker ('Will it require a firm grip? It's just that my wrist hurts ...')?

Comment: The sentence is unclear. Do you mean "held on to [something] with my hand"? It is not clear what you are holding on to...

Comment: @JamesRandom It's just that I did not have seat belts so I had to use my hand to hold on in the car because if I would not to do it I would fly forward

Comment: @Karolina So I think that "... held on **with** my hand ..." would be best, without needing to say exactly what you held.

Comment: English doesn't use the "upside down" double quote.

Comment: Unlike many languages, English uses the possessive with body parts except with certain perpositional constructions. _He was hit in the head/in the stomach_, but _She injured her wrist. His hair is very curly._

Comment: It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are unclear in English. I think what you're trying to say is:

"Only my wrist hurts because I didn't use the seat-belts and I held on with my hand while braking."

Answer (score -2):

After editing she clarified a few things. She believes the reason she’s ok is because she wasn’t in a seat belt and she hurt her wrist because she wasn’t in a seat belt when something was breaking. It is still unclear what she was holding on with her hand or where her hand was, but it is acceptable that she states she (held on “by” hand) which indicates how the wrist was injured.

The person that changed her new edited version, in my opinion, took the sentence back where it was. More confusing when changed “on by hand” to “on to the hand”.

I’m not allowed to comment yet. So I gave my opinion her

Comment: What was breaking???